# Web Api Multiple actions were found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have actions that have different type parameters.

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{       
    [HttpPost]
    public UpdateFeatureResponse UpdateFeature(UpdateFeatureResuest reqResuest)
    {
        return new UpdateFeatureResponse { IsSuccess = true };
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public DeleteFeatureResponse DeleteFeature(DeleteFeatureRequest request)
    {
        return new DeleteFeatureResponse{ IsSuccess = true };
    }

}
```

And my request types are like this:

```
public class UpdateFeatureResuest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Feature { get; set; }
}

public class UpdateFeatureResponse
{
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
}

public class DeleteFeatureRequest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class DeleteFeatureResponse
{
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
}
```

Route is here:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

When I send request (`http://localhost:52285/api/My/UpdateFeature`) via fiddler it returns **HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error**

Error message is :

> {"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"Multiple actions were found that match the request: \r\nUpdateFeature on type WebGUI.Controllers.MyController\r\nDeleteFeature on type WebGUI.Controllers.MyController","exceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","stackTrace":" .....

Comment: What URL did you use and what does your routing look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your route is wrong as it doesn't specify the action name so it's treating the `UpdateFeature` part as the ID parameter. Change it to this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: My route is default route of web api template. But your solution is worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Better to use `Route` attribute.

For example

```
[RoutePrefix("myapi")]
public class MyController : ApiController
{       
    [Route("update")]
    [HttpPost]
    public UpdateFeatureResponse UpdateFeature(UpdateFeatureResuest reqResuest)
    {
        return new UpdateFeatureResponse { IsSuccess = true };
    }

    [Route("delete")]
    [HttpPost]
    public DeleteFeatureResponse DeleteFeature(DeleteFeatureRequest request)
    {
        return new DeleteFeatureResponse{ IsSuccess = true };
    }

}
```

Now add this to your `WebApiConfig` before `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute()`

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```